# htaccess Remove last char from url

Tags: .htaccess

h3llo, one of my URL's has a & at the end which I want removed using a rewriterule in a .htaccess file. I've been searching around for a while now and although I found a lot of information I just can't seem to get it to work.
This is what I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)&$
RewriteRule ^(&)?$ /$1 [L]
```

I'm using CodeIgniter the build my site, in case that matters. I'm also sure that mod_rewrite is turned on.
Thank you.

Comment: Is it not possible to fix the originating URL? An `&` at the end is technically malformed anyway.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to post to facebook. After a user is logged in they are redirected to my site, but the site works with jquery tabs. So I want a #my-tab3 behind the url to make it open in the right tab. But facebook adds a lot of stuff to url including the & at the end. Thats why my js can't read the tabs-tag. I though htaccess would be an easy fix but for some reason it's just not working. The url I get looks kind of like this: www.mysite.com/ci/index.php/main?state=c32cb8ed2856b8d&code=AQAsHxQ-cdkpm5-k405-kdQS9M94bfiO8e0gQfA7GScPQY#ui-tabs-6&

Comment: @renne `&` in the end of **query string** is perfectly OK, and it cannot be rewritten, too (it is not part of URI). The code i gave you below will only get rid of & in the end of URI...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)&$ $1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. The code didn't work, I wonder what the problem is...

Comment: No need for backslash there actually. Updated the code (removed backslash) and removed / before `$1` so it will actually work within any folder, not just root

Comment: The code does seem to work at times. Lets say I have an index.php inside a map. www.site.com/map& works, it shows the url without the & and opens index.php, Www.site.com/map/& shows the url including the & but still does open index file like it should. Does that make any sense?

Comment: The time when you see a real redirect (& sign disappear) is because you hit a directory without trailing slash - Apache performs that redirect. Since i did not add `R` flag, in the rest of the cases, apache does not redirect the browser, it does sub-request by itself.

Comment: Ah i see, thanks that's pretty helpful for me. The code you gave me obviously is functioning as it should, so I guess the problem must lie with the CodeIgniter framework I'm using. I'll ask around on their forum for more information. Thanks for the help.